# if NSDate is Monday

Tags: iphone, nsdate

How can I check if an NSDate is a specific day of the week, like a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, and so on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From memory (I don't have an ObjC environment handy at the moment):

```
int yourDOW = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
    fromDate:yourDate] weekday];
if (yourDOW == 2) { ... }     // Sun = 1, Sat = 7
```

In other words:

- Get the user's current calendar.
- Get the weekday unit based on the given date.
- Get the week day from that.
- Compare it with what you want.

Comment: Would 1 be Sunday, or would 0 be Sunday?

Comment: It depends on your calendar, see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html for details: Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n  is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1.

Comment: I think its best answer